# Rendering a form dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have written functional based component i am  checking the type in the switch case ,depending on the type i am creating the form here

```
const component = (props) => {
    let renderObject = null
    let obj;
    const renderdata = () =>{
        console.log(props);
        obj = Object.keys(props.todoprop).map((todoproprties) =>{
            console.log("here we are looking at the data" , props.todoprop[todoproprties])
            let toDoProprties = props.todoprop[todoproprties]
             switch(props.todoprop[todoproprties].type){
                 case 'text':
                     return <input type="text"  key="1"  value={toDoProprties.value}  name = {toDoProprties.name} onChange={props.handleChange} />
                 case 'date':
                     return  <input type="date" key="2" value={toDoProprties.value}  onChange={props.handleChange}/>
                 default:
                    return <textarea rows="10" key="3" cols="30"  rows="10" cols="30"   value={toDoProprties.value} onChange={props.handleChange}/>

             }

        })
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello from component </h1>
            {renderdata()}
            <div className="card">
             <div className="card-body">
              <div>
              {obj}
              <button type="submit" onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
              </div>
             </div>
             </div>
            {console.log(props)}

        </div>
    );

    }
export default component;
```

Below is the container in which  am rendering  my component

```
class container extends Component {
    state = {
        // how i want my data to look  with  a heading with date proprtey and a description
        heading: '',
        date: '',
        description: '', 
        Todo: {
            heading: { type: "text", value: "", placeholder: 'plese enter heading', name:"heading"},
            date: { type: "date", value: "", placeholder: "plese enter date", name: "date" },
            description: {  value: "PLESE DESIGN A GOOD TODO",  placeholder: 'plese enter description',  name: "description"}
        }
    }

    onChangeHandler = (event) =>{
        console.log(event.value)
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name] : event.target.value
        })
        // this.setState({Todo.heading.value: event.target.value })
    }

    onSubmitHandler = () =>{

        console.log("you have succesfully clicked the handler")
        console.log("you are seeing the state" ,this.state.heading);
        console.log("you are seeing the description", this.state.description)
    }

    render() {
        var dataPassingHandler = () => {
            return (<div>
                <Dynamiccomponent  todoprop={this.state.Todo}   handleChange={this.onChangeHandler}  handleSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}/>
            </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {dataPassingHandler()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default container;
```

1) In my container i am rendering the component and  i am passing the type to the container and i am checking in the   switch case i am creating the form

2) I am stuck here with two problems First one is how to pass the onChange ,

3) Second how to handle the onclick and create a new object  in state of the container

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting form correctly?

Comment: i am unable to type anything in my input fields

Comment: Why do you have complex Todo state? Can't you directly have Todo array?

Comment: yes but i  want to learn (i am new to react ) in first try i used  array  next i want to give a try how to extract data if object type is given then i continued with the flow (i forgot to change i taught it 's  working and continued )

Comment: Anything is okay i just want  know how to add state of the todo dynamically  and make onChange work

Comment: Hi venkatesh, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to type in, because you have binded the value from `Todo` object,

```
<input type="text"  key="1"  value={toDoProprties.value}  name = {toDoProprties.name} onChange={props.handleChange} />
```

But you are not changing value in `Todo` object here,

```
onChangeHandler = (event) =>{
    console.log(event.value)
    this.setState({
       [event.target.name] : event.target.value
    })
    // this.setState({Todo.heading.value: event.target.value })
}
```

The above change handler is only changing state variable, which is directly available in state. But you need to change the value in `Todo` object, you can do this way,

```
onChangeHandler = (event) => {
   //let's take name and value in a variable so that it can be accesiable in complex state updation
   let name = event.target.name;
   let value = event.target.value;

   //This is the object from Todo which needs to be updated
   let updatedTodo = this.state.Todo[name];

   //this is the functional setState, which take's previous state value to calculate the next state
   this.setState(prevState => ({
       Todo: { ...prevState.Todo, [name]: {...updatedTodo, value: value} }
   }))
}
```

Now your input's are fully controlled and you can type in.

Also you need to make some change's in your `Dynamiccomponent`. For the changes you can compare your code with this demo,

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s44qqb)

**Note:** Take some note's here.

1. In react component name should be in `PascalCase`. For example, `Dynamiccomponent` should be `DynamicComponent`, `container` should be `Container` and so on.
2. In your component where you have created your dynamic input's, you should provide `name` to every input / texteare so that your `onChange` handler work smoothly.

Comment: @venkatesh, just understand how `functional setState` work. You can search on internet.

Comment: Thanks it is working but  i if i change  once the onchange all the three i can see in the console.log   i think i missed something can you plese help me or  i am in the correct path

Comment: You are getting complete Todo object right? It is correct.

Comment: You'r printing todoprop here `console.log(props.todoprop);`, so even only 1 input changes you will see complete Todo object.

Comment: I don't know why my account is blcoked   i am working with the todo now i am updating my component with component did mount i am facing a issue could you plese help me

Comment: https://codepen.io/mdvenkatesh1421/pen/MWgZBWG?editors=1010  i tryied statically it is working  but when passing like these i am  failing i even tryed with spread operator here is my codepen link just pasted the line where i am getting the issue plese help me

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh, instead of `this.state.Todo.proptype` you should use this `this.state.Todo[proptype]`. Here prototype is dynamic key, and dynamic key is needs to be accessed using `[]`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your support  i don't what is wrong with my code i want get data from my axios node backed i used component did mount to update the state and send the data in console.log data is printing but not on card sorry to bother you (i tryed same way with json place holder seems good but in this app not working) https://codepen.io/mdvenkatesh1421/pen/orjBpV(codepen link)

Comment: i have done using axios  for json place holder using arrays now i am unable to render object is it possible to render object type

Comment: Can you create an another question for this, I will try to anwser and solve your issue.

Comment: yes but from another account because they blocked these account i will give you the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066545/calling-a-component-from-a-container-and-rendering-the-form-based-on-input-param

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh will look into this soon.

Comment: Got it i  am not returning (means not saving )the state after updating(in this.SetState)  so the component is not rendering

Comment: var a = 10, d , v can you explain these syntax and what it is called