# Calling a component from a container and rendering the form based on Input parameters given from parent container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Following is my code for Todo component where i am rendering my component named Dynamic component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Dynamiccomponent from '../components/ToDo/Todocomponent';
    import  Navbar  from '../components/Nav/Navbar';
    import  AxiosInstance from './AxiosInstance';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    import { prototype } from 'stack-utils';


    class container extends Component {
        state = {
            // how i want my data to look  with  a heading with date proprtey and a description
            Todo: {
                heading: { type: "text", value: " ", placeholder: 'plese enter heading', name:"heading"},
                date: { type: "date", value: " ", placeholder: "plese enter date", name: "date" },
                description: {  value: " ",  placeholder: 'plese enter description',  name: "description"}
            },
        }

        // It will be called after total  form is loded 

        componentDidMount(){
            AxiosInstance.get('/todos').then((data) =>{
                console.log("these is the data you have entered in db",data);
                let dataFromServer =  data.data.data.map((data) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                     Object.keys(this.state.Todo).map((proptype)=>{
                         this.setState (prevState => {
                            prevState.Todo[proptype].value = data[proptype]

                         })
                         console.log("we are seeing the updated state",this.state.Todo)

                    })
                    })

                }) 
        }


        onChangeHandler = (event) =>{
            // declare some varables
            let name = event.target.name;
            let value = event.target.value;
            let updatedTodo = this.state.Todo[name];
            console.log(updatedTodo)
            //best logic i have seen 
            this.setState(prevState =>({
                Todo: {...prevState.Todo, [name] : {...updatedTodo, value:value}} 
            }))

            console.log(event.value)
            this.setState({
                [event.target.name] : event.target.value
            })
            // this.setState({Todo.heading.value: event.target.value })
        }

        // we are submiting to the server
        onSubmitHandler = (event) =>{

            console.log("you have succesfully clicked the handler",this.state.Todo.heading.value)
            let todoData =  { heading: this.state.Todo.heading.value,
                                date: this.state.Todo.date.value,
                                description : this.state.Todo.description.value}
            console.log("we are seeing the todo here",todoData);

            AxiosInstance.post('/newtodo',todoData).then((res) =>{
                console.log(res);
            })

        }



        render() {
            var dataPassingHandler = () => {
                return (
                <div>
                    <Dynamiccomponent  todoprop={this.state.Todo}   handleChange={this.onChangeHandler}  handleSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler} 
                    handleEdit = {this.editHandler}   handledelete={this.deleteHandler}/>
                </div>
                )
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    <Navbar/>
                    {dataPassingHandler()}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


  export default container;
```

Following is my code  for component where i am checking the type and displaying the data in card
    import React from 'react';

```
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

    // now created a  component 
    const component = (props) => {
        let renderObject = null
        let obj;
        const renderdata = () =>{
            console.log(props);
            obj = Object.keys(props.todoprop).map((todoproprties) =>{
                console.log("[here we are looking at the data from todo component]" , props.todoprop[todoproprties])
                let toDoProprties = props.todoprop[todoproprties]
                 switch(props.todoprop[todoproprties].type){
                     case 'text':

                        return <input type="text"  key="1"  value={toDoProprties.value}  name ={toDoProprties.name} onChange={props.handleChange} placeholder = {toDoProprties.placeholder} className="card-title" style={{dispay: "block"}}/> 
                     case 'date':
                         return  <input type="date" key="2" value={toDoProprties.value}  onChange={props.handleChange} name={toDoProprties.name} placeholder = {toDoProprties.placeholder} className="card-text" style={{display:"block" }}/>
                     default:
                        return <textarea  rows="4" cols="50"  key= "3" value={toDoProprties.value}  name= {toDoProprties.name} onChange={props.handleChange} placeholder = {toDoProprties.placeholder} className="card-text" style={{ display: "block"}}/>

                 }

            })
        }



        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello from component </h1>
                {renderdata()}
                <div className="card w-75">
                 <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">To do list</h5>   
                  <div>
                  {obj}
                  <br/>
                  <button type="submit" onClick={props.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  <button type="submit" onClick={props.handleEdit} className="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                  <button type="submit" onClick={props.handledelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
                {console.log(props)}

            </div>
        );

        }
    export default component;
```

1)In the container (class based component ) I have used axios in componentDidMount to get the data and i have changed to componentWillMount (But nothing worked inside my code)

2)In componentDidMount first i got the data and sliced it and changed the state using setSate 
for conformation i have o/p the changed state

```
 date: {type: "date", value: "2019-09-19", placeholder: "plese enter date", name: "date"}
description: {value: "vrrrrr", placeholder: "plese enter description", name: "description"}
heading: {type: "text", value: "Headinsssssssssssssg", placeholder: "plese enter heading", name: "heading"}
__proto__: Object
```

**My component is rendering first than my container (i can say that by my console.log  ) It is not rendering second time when my state is changed i don't why**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following issue is because of not changing the state properly and updating  it

I have changed the following lines of code in component did mount now it worked

```
componentDidMount(){
        AxiosInstance.get('/todos').then((data) =>{
            console.log("these is the data you have entered in db",data);
            let dataFromServer =  data.data.data.map((data) =>{
                console.log(data);
                 Object.keys(this.state.Todo).map((proptype)=>{
                     console.log("////////////////////", this.state.Todo[proptype].value)
                     let StateKeyValue = this.state.Todo[proptype].value;
                     let dynamicValue = data[proptype];
                     console.log("[we are seeing the dynamic value before entering into the state]" ,  " ", StateKeyValue );
                     this.setState(prevState =>({
                        Todo : {...prevState.Todo, [proptype] : {... dynamicValue, value: dynamicValue } }
                     }))

                })
                })
```